# how to model google analytics data in database

Tags: google-analytics, data-modeling, google-analytics-filters

how to model google analytics data in database. I am using pentaho to bring the google analytics data in to my database, but i am not sure how to model the data into tables.
Any reference,suggestion is most welcome.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You could be inspired by the schema used by Google Analytics to export 98% of the original hit data + data processing outcomes into Big Query.
The feature is only available for Analytics 360 customers, but the schema is public.
You've got a visualisation here https://storage.googleapis.com/e-nor/visualizations/bigquery/ga360-schema.html

However, it's unlikely that can get export as fine grained data through the export API (you will face usage [quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas), aggregates,...). But that gives you a starting point.

You can probably challenge the expected usages of that data to focus on data you really need to export and ajust your data model to your use cases.